# Evaluate $\iint_B xy^2 \ dxdy$ with $B$ bounded by $x = \sin(\pi y), y=(x+1)^3, y=-1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Evaluate the double integral
>
> $$\iint_B xy^2 \ dxdy$$
>
> where $B$ is the area bounded by the following constraints:
>
> $x = \sin(\pi y)$
>
> $y=(x+1)^3$
>
> $y=-1$

I do not see how I should find the boundaries for the integrals on this one. Could you help me?

Below I you can see the plot I made with Geogebra.

[image]
EDIT: With this picture in mind I think it would be best to set the boundaries as follows:

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{\sqrt[3]{y}-1}^{\sin(\pi y)}xy^2 \ dxdy$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[3]{y}-1\le x\le\sin(\pi y)$

Comment: there is something wrong, maybe you mean $y\ge -1$ instead? As you have actually written you have that $x=-2$ and $x=\sin(-\pi)=0$, what doesn't make sense

Comment: @Masacroso: No, there are always equality signs.

Comment: ok, I understand the notation. From the picture you can see that the values of $y$ goes from $-1$ to $1$ and for each chosen $y$ value the values of $x$ goes from the solution of the equation $y=(x+1)^3$ to $x=\sin(\pi y)$, that is the integral that you had written

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help.